# HTTP Access to Analysis Services through IIS 10.0 not working

Tags: http, iis, ssas, olap

i followed all the steps mentioned in the below link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/configure-http-access-to-analysis-services-on-iis-8-0
But when i connect to http://servername/OLAP/msmdpump.dll in my SQL Server Management Studio i get the below error

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to http://ServerName/olap/msmdpump.dll.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The connection either timed out or was lost. (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AppLocal.AdomdClient)

---

The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed. (System)

Comment: Try this first, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Comment: try to enable anonymous authentication.